# Enable a readonly view to Laravel Nova without login

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I'm using Laravel Nova to make a collaborative Wiki for songs. I would like an unauthenticated user be able to see the songs, but not collaborate. He would be able to collaborate only after registering a new account.

I tried to comment the `Laravel\Nova\Http\Middleware\Authenticate` middleware, in file `'web'` middleware in `config/nova.php`.

Now, it still works for my superAdmin, and my simple user, but for the unauthenticated user, it can reach nova dashboard without login, but there is no more items in left menus. The only way to make them appear is to remove the custom policies I have defined for my resources.

Why is it happening, and what should I do to

Comment: Policies are meant to be applied to authenticated users only. If you want things to be accessible when not authenticated as well you'd need to remove any sort of policy check on those particular things

Comment: oohhh, I see, you could put it as an answer !

Comment: Actually that was incorrect. Take a look at [guest users](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#guest-users) in the docs. It might make things a bit more streamlined

Comment: I tested it, and it worked like a charm ! Thanks for your help !